Does the limit of these functions exist or not?
This question was asked in previous year exam of master's entrance and I have some questions in its solution which were given by the institute.

Question:  Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{ xy} { (x^2+y^2)^{\alpha} }$$ if $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $0$ if $(x,y)=0$.
Then which of the following is correct:


(a) For $\alpha =1/4 $, $f$ is continuous and differentiable.


(b) For $\alpha= 3/4$, $f$ is neither continuous nor differentiable.

Solution:
(a) If $\alpha= 1/4$ then put $x=r \cos\theta$ and $r = r \sin\theta$ and using this value in $f(x,y)$ we can see that as $r\to 0$ $f(x,y)=0$.
Let $f_x(0,0)= \alpha$ and $f_y(0,0)=\beta$. Now, for differentiability $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0) } \frac{ f(h,k) -f(0,0) -\alpha h -\beta k} { \sqrt{h^2 +k^2}}= \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{ hk } {( (h^2+ k^2)^{3/4}}$$
I understand the proof till now but in next step they write the limit on the RHS is $0$ without any explanation.
But I am not able to deduce how the limit equals $0$. Can you please help?
(b)  When $\alpha= 3/4$. I have proved that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Let $f_x(0,0)=\alpha$ and $f_y(0,0)= \beta$. Now, here they write that $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{ f(h,k) -f(0,0) -\alpha h -\beta k} {{ (h^2+ k^2)^{5/4}}}$$ does not exist. I can understand that how the limit in this case doesn't exists but if I use the same approach for (a) part, I think the limit of (a) part also don't exists.
So, how should I prove that the limit in (a) is $0$? Can you please help?

for part $(a)$ you can use polar coordinates

$x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$ and then apply squeeze theorem.

Set $h=R\cos\phi$ and $k=R\sin\phi$, then
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{hk}{(h^2+k^2)^{3/4}}=\lim_{R\to0}\frac{R^2\sin\phi\cos\phi}{R^{3/2}}=\lim_{R\to0}R^{1/2}\sin\phi\cos\phi=0$$
since $|R^{1/2}\sin\phi\cos\phi|\leq R^{1/2}$ by squeeze theorem.
You can try doing the other one similarly. Hope this helps. :)
